# email verification and forgot password being tag as spam in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, email

I upload my app on siteground. I ask them already a bunch of question regarding this issue and they just gave me links to their tech articles, followed them but still doesn't work. I been searching for an answer for too long. I hope you can suggest a procedure or help me to fix this.

The issue I am having is the email verification and forgot password is being sent to spam section or in some other instance it is blocked due to security reason.

**here's the bounce email I am receiving**

[image]

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  user@gmail.com
    host outbound.mailspamprotection.com [xx.xxx.xxx.xx]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    550 This message has been reported as spam by other users.
Reporting-MTA: dns; xxxxxxx.siteground.xxxxxx

**Action:** failed
**Final-Recipient:** rfc822;user@gmail.com
**Status:** 5.0.0
**Remote-MTA:** dns; outbound.mailspamprotection.com
**Diagnostic-Code:** smtp; 550 This message has been reported as spam by other users.
```

**MESSAGE HEADER**

```
**Return-path:** <>
**Envelope-to:** serveremail@mysite.com
**Delivery-date:** Fri, 26 Nov 2021 19:16:44 +0000
**Received:** from mailnull by xxxxxxxx.siteground.xxxxxx with local (Exim 4.90-.1)
    id 1mqgiC-000Aqa-Ln
    for serveremail@mysite.com; Fri, 26 Nov 2021 19:16:44 +0000
**X-Failed-Recipients:** user@gmail.com
**Auto-Submitted:** auto-replied
**From:** Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@sgp1000.siteground.asia>
**To:** serveremail@mysite.com
**References:** <f1bb46cdbbacd8db694337f14ad1fafc@127.0.0.1>
**Content-Type:** multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status; boundary=1637954204-eximdsn-1244935018
**MIME-Version:** 1.0
**Subject:** Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
**Message-Id:** <E1mqgiC-000Aqa-Ln@sgp1000.siteground.asia>
**Date:** Fri, 26 Nov 2021 19:16:44 +0000
```

here's what I have in my env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_HOST=xxxxxxx.siteground.xxxxxx
MAIL_USERNAME=serveremail@site.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='mypassword'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=serveremail@site.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME='my app name'
```

I have other notification functions my app that notify/email the admins. It triggers when some certain actions are made like if there's new application etc. those notifications are being sent to inbox and not in spam.

Any suggestions? or links with really working steps that I can follow? Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: There are numerous reasons why an email may be marked as spam. Some of the potentially "quick wins" are listed here: https://www.siteground.co.uk/kb/emails-treated-spam/. Is the domain for your site fairly new?

Comment: It's morethan 2 years old but the app is use just recently.

Comment: Try using something like: https://www.mail-tester.com/ to get more of an insight in to what your issues are.

Comment: I sent mail to mail-tester.com, the result has 4 checks and 1 blacklisted, "You're listed in 1 blacklist. Listed in BACKSCATTERER ( -0.5 )" what does it mean? and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I just reset to default the  SPF and activate and deactivate DKIM... I'll update this if that works.